# Graph listerner Jmeter Remote

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I try to use jmeter with two injector to make some tests. I've installed the plugin "Graph Generator Listener" but when I launch the test with the parameter -r, the graphs are not generated. If I just run the test without the injector, graphs are generated.

Do you have an Idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it should not be any difference in standalone or distributed mode as you [should not have any listeners enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) in any case.

So I would recommend the following:

1. Delete (or at least disable) all the listeners in your Test Plan
2. Run your test
3. When it finishes and you get ".jtl" results file you can have another ["fake run"](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/#Generate-CSV-PNG-for-existing-previous-test-results) with 1 thread, 1 iteration and 1 sampler which does nothing just to generate CSV and/or PNG reports out of the existing .jtl results file.